# Understanding regex with OR

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like this: ('0'|['0'‐'9']+'.'['0'‐'9' 'a'‐'f']*)

In order to test it I am using a handy tool called http://www.regexpal.com/
The thing is that I am getting stuck when trying to understand the logic, inserting a '0' is fine but then I don't get why the OR prevents inserting other characters. Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have quotes in your regex ? And what are you trying to match with your regex ? Some valid examples would be helpful.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish with this regex so that I can even play around with it, can you please [edit] in some of your test cases and expected results?

Comment: It's currently expecting '.' to be part of the input other than '0', I presume including the single quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand how the brackets in the regex are working. It isn't the OR part that is preventing you.

```
('0'|['0'‐'9']+'.'['0'‐'9' 'a'‐'f']*)
```

Will match either `'0'` with the quotes or for example `0000000'z''''9` or anything else like it. The quotes are treated as literal and the period must be escaped because it is a wildcard.

```
(0|[0-9]+\.[0-9a-f]*)
```

May be what you are looking for. This will match values such as `0` or `23.` or `3.14159`

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems in your regex (as others have pointed out), but I'll explain something about alternations.

Most regex flavors will short-circuit alternations.

This means that you should reorder it, if you want it to match the other expression first.